# Design pattern for one-or-many conditionals

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit, conditional-statements

I have a bunch of Junit tests that derive from a base abstract class. In my test method in the base class, I want to be able to use a combination of one or multiple features (say, Feature1, Feature2, Feature3 etc.). That is, a test can use just Feature2, while another test can have all three.

```
public void test() throws Exception
{
    if (feature1)
        // do something1

    if (feature2)
        // do something2

    if (feature3)
        // do something3

    // there can be more features

    if (no feature used)
        // do "default"
}
```

What would be the best choice of design pattern in this case? I am looking into the COMMAND pattern, but it appears that I can use one Command at any given time. My requirement is to be able to use anything between none to all commands/features.

Note, that the Junit test classes are all auto-generated (default, that is no special feature). Any test that requires a customization would have to inherit a feature, and the customization would have to be built by modifying the auto-generated class for that test only.

Comment: Why not just one test method for each feature and test case? Tests should be as simple as possible.

Comment: What is the implication of "using" a particular combination of features?  What impact does it have on your concrete test classes?

Comment: It would be easy to think the "features" more as flags. The test takes certain actions based on what flag or flags are set. The action for a feature can be as simple as setting an appropriate data file for a test running on a specific locale, to as complex as performing extraneous handling of files that is repetitive to certain tests (and hence isolated as a feature). In essence, each feature is exposed as a concrete class now that has a boolean method isFeatureEnabled().

Comment: Have you considered whether `org.junit.Assume` might be able to help you accomplish your goal? You'd probably need to deconstruct your test method, and that may not be possible, but `Assume` seems close to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: >> Any test that requires a customization would have to inherit a feature
>> each feature is exposed as a concrete class now.

how 2 features are possible?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, that's really the problem I am trying to solve. All the features are independent and implemented in certain ways resulting in a concrete class that exposes the feature. A test can "use" zero or one or more features. How can it do that without writing a nasty conditional statement?

Comment: @naspras i need some real code to answer, i don't understand how this boolean values are set for each test and how feature activation is triggered